# binding commands for control events like text changed in silverlight 3.5

Tags: silverlight

I got a requirement where i need to attach silverlight control events like text changed, lost focus to commands. we are using silverlight 3.5.

Please give me one sample example.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

There is an EventToCommand behavior:

> EventToCommand behavior, allowing you to bind any event of any UI element to an ICommand, for example on the ViewModel, directly in XAML. This makes using Commands much easier, without writing code behind. With the newest version, you can even get the EventArgs of the fired event directly in the ViewModel to handle it.

http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

Comment: This is good but we can't use this MVVM Light Toolkit in our project.

Answer (score 0):

this is really usefull article:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article859-command-binding-in-silverlight-4-stepbystep-.aspx

I dont see a reason to copy its sample sourcecodes here.